# When taking many screenshots with MSS, memory fills quickly and crashes python

Tags: python, memory, screenshot, python-mss

Here's my code:

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy as np

Frame = [0, 0, 1920, 1080]

def GetFrame():
    monitor = {"top": Frame[0], "left": Frame[1], "width": Frame[2], "height": Frame[3]}
    sct_img = mss.mss().grab(monitor)
    return np.asarray(sct_img)



while (True):
    inimg = GetFrame()
    cv2.imshow("WHY IS MEMORY SO HIGH???????", inimg)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When this runs, it doesn't throw any errors, but looking in task manager, my memory fills quickly (after 200 iterations or so), eventually crashing my desktop, then python. I have looked into [garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/gc.html), with no luck.

```
Python version 3.7.0
MSS version 4.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem myself. The issue was that `mss.mss()` instances must be closed, they do not automatically close during garbage collection (for whatever reason). The most convenient way to do that is by using a context manager:

```
def GetFrame():
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = {"top": Frame[0], "left": Frame[1], "width": Frame[2], "height": Frame[3]}
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        return np.asarray(sct_img)
```

As Tiger-222 points out, we can optimize this further by only creating a single `mss.mss()` object and using it throughout the entire program:

```py
monitor = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 1920, "height": 1080}

def get_frame(sct):
    return np.asarray(sct.grab(monitor))

with mss.mss() as sct:
  while True:
    img = get_frame(sct)
    cv2.imshow(img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You are right, using the context manager will free allocated resources. The documentation is pointing to those misuses: https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/usage.html#instance

Comment: You could do even better by moving the `while` inside the `mss` context manager. This way, you will avoid useless allocation/deacollcation each time you call `GetFrame`.